# error: conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string when updateCommand

Tags: gridview, sqldatasource

i have this gridview, and i use sqldatasource

this is my select command

```
SELECT Date.dateAvailable FROM LessonDate INNER JOIN Date ON LessonDate.dateID = Date.dateID WHERE (LessonDate.lessonID = @lessonID)
```

however when i want to update the dateAvailable column

```
UPDATE       Date
SET                dateAvailable = @dateAvailable
FROM            Date INNER JOIN
                         LessonDate ON Date.dateID = LessonDate.dateID
WHERE        (LesssonDate.dateID = @LessonDateID)
```

however it when i click on excute query it give me error conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

so what wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Your date is not in the correct format or is invalid. The problem is the most likely @dateAvailable. It is most likely

- Not a valid date/time, for example '2013-15-1' (15 month does not exists)
- out of range. SQL Server can represent date between certain values.
- @dateAvailable contains a null or totall in valid value.
- commas's are missing from your @dateAvailable field

To troubleshoot this, change the @dateAvailable to correct date (for testing only)

```
UPDATE date 
SET    dateavailable = '2013-1-1'   <-- I changed only this value 
FROM   date 
       INNER JOIN lessondate 
               ON date.dateid = lessondate.dateid 
WHERE  ( lesssondate.dateid = @LessonDateID )
```

Run the above query inside your program. If it runs, that means you problem is indeed the datetime value. Alternatively you can print out the query in a label control and see exactly what your query is.

Comment: @BlueChippy I have add more code and explanation. I hope that helps.